# IllegalState Call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-viewgroup

My problem is, i am trying add custom library view to certain layouts.  I tried `catRow1.removeAllViews();` as specified on error, but it seems to not working. what am i doing wrong?

**//Fragment that fills view**

```
    monthlyLimit = (LinearLayout)     getActivity().findViewById(R.id.monthlyLimit);
    catRow1 = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.catRow1);
    catRow2 = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.catRow2);
    cat1 = (LinearLayout) catRow1.findViewById(R.id.cat1);
    cat2 = (LinearLayout) catRow1.findViewById(R.id.cat2);
    cat3 = (LinearLayout) catRow2.findViewById(R.id.cat3);
    cat4 = (LinearLayout) catRow2.findViewById(R.id.cat4);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams  lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mPieChart = new DrawDonut(getActivity());
    monthlyLimit.addView(mPieChart.getChart(), lp);
    catRow1.removeAllViewsInLayout();
    catRow1.removeAllViews();
    cat1.addView(mPieChart.getChart(), lp);
```

The layout that is added

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"      android:weightSum="10"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/budgetLayout">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/monthlyLimit" android:layout_margin = "5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="4"/>

<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/catRow1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_margin = "5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="3">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat1" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat2" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/catRow2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_margin = "5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="3">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat3" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cat4" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **class LayoutInflater** in method ***onCreateView*** in **Fragment**:

```
View inflate;
LinearLayout monthlyLimit;
LinearLayout catRow1;
LinearLayout catRow2;
LinearLayout cat1;
LinearLayout cat2;
LinearLayout cat3;
LinearLayout cat4;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);

    monthlyLimit = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.monthlyLimit);
    catRow1 = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.catRow1);
    catRow2 = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.catRow2);

    cat1 = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.cat1);
    cat2 = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.cat2);
    cat3 = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.cat3);
    cat4 = (LinearLayout) inflate.findViewById(R.id.cat4);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams  lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mPieChart = new DrawDonut(getActivity());
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            monthlyLimit.addView(mPieChart.getChart(), lp);
            catRow1.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            catRow1.removeAllViews();
            cat1.addView(mPieChart.getChart(), lp);
        }
    });

    return inflate;
}
```